# Error installing jekyll - Package metadata is missing

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

I am trying to install **Jekyll** and use it to create a **GitHub website** with markdown. I use Debian 9 and gem 2.7.3

$ **sudo update_rubygems**

[image: Error Code]

And if I just want to install Jekyll :

$ **sudo gem install Jekyll**

```
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
invalid gem: package metadata is missing in
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/cache/jekyll-3.6.2.gem
```

I expected the result to be a complete installation of Jekyll without errors of missing packages.

I get several errors of not existing softwares such as :

- jekyll !!!!!
- kramdown !!!
- listen !!!
- rouge !!!
- sass !!!

Answer (score 1):

it can be fixed by removing the cached gem meta data file. in your case it is `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/cache/jekyll-3.6.2.gem`

so to fix remove this file

```
rm /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/cache/jekyll-3.6.2.gem
```

then try installing the gem again

```
gem install jekyll -v '3.6.2'
```

then try updating rubygems again. it will work.